# AngularJS: Repeating and getting values from checkbox in table

Tags: angularjs

I have an object named `studentData` which has a number of attributes. I have a table corresponding to a certain number of questions. What I intend to do is, for each student, check the value of question number which is correct and push into `studentData.correctQuestionNumbers` which is an array.
However, the checkboxes don't seem to repeat.

View:

```
<table class="flat-table flat-table-3">
    <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th ng-repeat="questionNumber in questionNumbers">{{ questionNumber }}</th>         
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="student in studentData">
        <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="questionNumber in questionNumbers"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.correctQuestionNumbers[]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.questionNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    $scope.correctQuestionNumbers = [];

$scope.selectStudents = [{batch:'A1', name: 'ABC'}, {batch:'A2', name: 'XYZ'}];

$scope.studentData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedStudents.length; i++){
  $scope.studentData.push({name: $scope.selectedStudents[i].name, 
    batch: $scope.selectedStudents[i].batch, 
    correctQuestionNumbers: $scope.correctQuestionNumbers});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.questionNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
$scope.selectedStudents = [{batch:'A1', name: 'ABC'}, {batch:'A2', name: 'XYZ'}];

$scope.studentData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selectedStudents.length; i++){
  $scope.studentData.push({name: $scope.selectedStudents[i].name, 
    batch: $scope.selectedStudents[i].batch, 
    correctQuestionNumbers: []});
}
```

**View:**

```
<table class="flat-table flat-table-3">
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th ng-repeat="questionNumber in questionNumbers">{{ questionNumber }}</th>         
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="student in studentData">
    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="questionNumber in questionNumbers"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.correctQuestionNumbers[$index]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please tell why this works?

Comment: But @HARI I cant update the `correctQuestionNumbers` of both students differenty. It seems they are both same everytime.

Comment: is the check box is checked for both students ?

Comment: Yes, when I click for one it gets updated for both for same values. But I  intend to change it differently for different students. The students wont have same question numbers correct.

Comment: did you modified your controller `correctQuestionNumbers: []` while pushing  student data `$scope.studentData.push`

Comment: Oh yes. My bad. Sorry. Thanks a lot.